# find unique strings in data frame variables

Tags: r, dataframe, character, unique, element

I have a data frame with several character variables, I want to find the unique string in each row. There is only a certain string duplicated in several columns per row, surrounded by NAs. I.E. the data frame "df":

```
  Col1 Col2 Col3
1 ABC  ABC  NA
2  NA  DEF  DEF
3 GHI  NA   NA
4 JKL  JKL  JKL
```

As an output I would like to have

```
ABC
DEF
GHI
JKL
```

Best would be to have some kind of apply function for each row. I tried out several variations of

```
apply(df,1, function(x) unique(x))
```

But that was not successful. I think there is quite an easy way, if you know the correct function? How can I do that?

Comment: If there's only a single unique element per row (which may be duplicated in that or row or not), you can use `df[cbind(1:nrow(df), max.col(!is.na(df)))]` without looping

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `is.na` to remove the NA elements

```
unname(apply(df, 1, FUN = function(x) unique(x[!is.na(x)])))
#[1] "ABC" "DEF" "GHI" "JKL"
```

If there are more than one `unique` element per row, it will return as a `list` (depending upon whether the number of elements are different for each row).  In that case, we can `paste` them together to create a single string

```
unname(apply(df, 1, FUN = function(x) toString(unique(x[!is.na(x)]))))
```

---

Another option is `pmax` if there is only a single unique element per row

```
 do.call(pmax, c(df, list(na.rm=TRUE)))
 #[1] "ABC" "DEF" "GHI" "JKL"
```

Comment: Thanks, Akrun. The first is my preferred method. As I assumed, I was not to far away from the solution. But, I did not need unname.

Answer (score 1):

Another option

```
levels(unlist(df))
```

Comment: I think this might fail if several rows had the same unique values in the sense that they would only be reported once (the level) but not for each row

Comment: @docendodiscimus : Definitely. This is situation specified solution. I think this is the easiest way in this particular problem to achieve the goal.